# popup is not closing in firefox

Tags: firefox

Hi I have a jquery function that closes when the user click on the close button in the div or hits enter. Its working fine in chrome. But in firefox, if I click anywhere on the html page and then hit enter its closing. Pls revert back soon with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it'd be nice to have at least some code examples, without any informations its hard to evaluate.

Comment: First, you have posted a _problem_, not a _question_. I suppose we can imply "how do I fix that?" Second, you have not given us the code that we can debug, or even _any_ way for us to access the code. Please give us some code.

Comment: OH sorry. Anyways I have fixed the bug. Thanks alot for your reply.